# I am getting a error of STATICFILE DIR in python

Tags: django-templates

WARNINGS:
?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'E:\Python Practice\Django\userproject\static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write  in `settings.py` file  :

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write static files directory to serve the static content in settings.py file as :

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on experience, it might differ.
if you are using the build explicitly in versel.json it will override the versel default build functions.

```
{
    "src": "build.sh",
    "use": "@vercel/static-build",
    "config": {
      "distDir": "staticfiles"
    }
  }
```

if you try to remove the above part from your code and just mention the correct paths of static root in settings.py it will work,

```
"builds": [
  {
    "src": "Zombies/wsgi.py",
    "use": "@vercel/python"    
  }
],
```

Only this much is sufficient in build part of vercel.json